# Remove the one part from SEF link joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I' trying to make `SEF` URL in my Joomla site which is `root/<menu-item-alias>/<view-name>/<item-alias>` something like that.

I realize that if I add anything to return value of function `MyComponentBuildRoute()` in `route.php`, It always appear on my URL:

```
$segments[] = $view;
$segments[] = $item_alias;
return $segments;
```

I take a look at com_content in Joomla and it doesn't have the `<view-name>` part, just `root/<menu-item-alias>/<item-alias>` however in the code there is still something like

`$segments[] = $view;`

How can I do just like the default `com_content` do? How can I remove the view-name part or any other part from my `SEF` link ?

Answer (score 2):

Editing the joomla core is not recommended, if you can do it without modifying the core it would be great. I'd suggest to use Artio JoomSEF, it is a component that lets you edit your SEF urls, so you can decide, for each page, what your url will be after www.yourdomain.tld/

[image]

full image at: http://www.diystash.com/sefproblem.png

Hope this helped

Comment: I'm not edditng Joomla core, I'm working on my own component and I want to apply my SEF Link config onto it

Answer (score 0):

**in BuildRoute():**

Add to $segments only those values which you want to see in the url;

```
$segments[] = $query['task'];
```

then delete the variable otherwise it will be still added as a query param:

```
unset($query['task']);
```

so for example if you want to get rid of the layout parameter, and don't care about its value, just

```
unset($query['layout']);
```

**in ParseRoute():**

assuming $vars is the array you're returning, just assign the segments you need from the url segments, but make sure to recreate those you need: i.e. view etc. so to restore the layout param:

```
$vars['layout']='mydefaultlayout';
```

This way you won't show what's not needed, and still let your component receive the properly initialized params.